# How to import data from django.models, to use in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-models, django-templates

I am trying to import a python dictionary from moodels and manipulate/print it's properties in Javascript. However nothing seems to print out and I don't receive any error warnings.

**Views.py**

```
from chesssite.models import Chess_board
import json

def chess(request):
    board = Chess_board()
    data = json.dumps(board.rep)
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'board': data})
```

Here board.rep is a python dictionary  {"0a":0, "0b":0, "0c":"K0"} - basically a chess board

**home.html**

```
<html>
   <body>
      {% block content %}
         <script>
            for (x in {{board}}) {
               document.write(x)
            }
         </script>
      {% endblock %}
   </body>
</html>
```

I also would very much appreciate some debugging tips!
Thanks in advance, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django defaults to escaping things as HTML, and that will make `"` into `@quot;`. Try changing `{{board}}` into `{{board|safe}}` to prevent the html escaping. Alternatively, in the view you can wrap the string in `mark_safe()` which is in `django.utils.safestring` to indicate that the string shouldn't be escaped.

Answer (score 1):

To transfer data between django and javascript, dump data in django view and load in a javascript variable. Try to avoid django interpolation with javascript language constructs. It is unsafe, error prone, and can cause complexities.
in view

```
data = json.dumps(board.rep)
```

in template

```
const data = JSON.parse('{{ data|safe }}')
// use normal javascript here. 'data' is a javascript array

for (let x of data) {
    document.write(x)
}
```

Comment: You can do just `const data = {{ data|safe }}`.  There's not much point in wrapping it into a string and then parsing it again.  Also, you'll need an `|escapejs` instead of `|safe` to make sure quotes are properly escaped within a JS string.